# mysql replace content in field

Tags: mysql

I have a database called Database and a table called Table and a column in Table feed_meta that contains as part of the data this "&query=d|e|" in a much longer URL.  How do I find instances of this and replace with "&query=a|b|c|d|e|" without wiping out the other data parts of the URL string?

Comment: Is the data to be matched always in `&query=d|e` or could a valid match be `&query=a|d|e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table
set feed_meta = replace(feed_meta, '&query=d|e|', '&query=a|b|c|d|e|')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `Database`.`Table`
SET feed_meta = REPLACE(feed_meta, '&query=d|e|', '&query=a|b|c|d|e');
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace